# ANTLR4: Symbols '*' and '+' in the expressions

Tags: expression, antlr, antlr4, symbols

I am in the process of learning how to program a compiler through antlr. I looked around a bit to get some knowledge about it, so I ended up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286818/antlr4-parse-dot-ending-float-with-double-dots).

What I want to ask is that, what are each symbols doing?
The '?', '+' and '*' in the expression, what are they doing?

```
FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' {_input.LA(1) != '.'}?
 | [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;
```

Do any of you know where to start learning these expressions?

Comment: Those are called modifiers and are part of regular expressions. You surely shouldn't be writing parsers if you don't already know that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANTLR4 '+' operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580908/antlr4-operation)

Comment: This question should be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These symbols are a part of regular expressions, see this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) about regular expression in python (it's very similar in all languages).
the `*` means match the previous thing zero or more times, for example, `a*` will match  , `a`, `aa`, ...
the `+` means match the previous thing one or more times, for example, `a+` will match `a`, `aa`, ...
the `?` means match the previous thing zero or one times, for example, `a?` will match   or `a`.

Comment: One thing, how would you explain this expression: "[0-9]* '.' [0-9]+"?

Comment: the `[0-9]` part means "match any character between 0 and 9 inclusive" AKA a digit. So `[0-9]* '.' [0-9]+` means zero or more digits followed by a dot followed by one or more digits.